# splunk sdk java post process search

Tags: java, splunk

The splunk dashboard allows you to run a post-process search which uses a base search.I would like to know if the same can be achieved programatically using splunk sdk java.I would really appreciate if you could give me any pointers on this.

Given that we have a base search, using the Splunk Java SDK, we would like to do the below two steps
1) execute the base search and get the results with 'post process search 1', 
2) get the results from the base search that was executed previously with 'post process search2' and do something
I know step 1 is pretty straightforward, but would like to know how I can get the results from the base search executed in step#1 and apply it to the second post process search. Should I just get the results from the history? What is the best way to get the results from the base search job?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to build a dashboard with post process searches and look at what endpoints were being called using a recording proxy.

What was happening is a job with the base search was launched. Then when results were being retrieved, a post-processing search was being provided. In the raw REST API this is [the search parameter](http://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/6.4.2/RESTREF/RESTsearch#search.2Fjobs.2F.7Bsearch_id.7D.2Fresults) on the search job results (and the preview results) endpoint which was being called.

Now I haven't tried it explicitly, but correspondingly, there's a setSearch method on the [JobResultsArgs](http://docs.splunk.com/DocumentationStatic/JavaSDK/1.5.0/com/splunk/JobResultsArgs.html#setSearch(java.lang.String)) object (and similar for the JobResultsPreviewArgs object) that you'd pass to [Job#getResults](http://docs.splunk.com/DocumentationStatic/JavaSDK/1.5.0/com/splunk/Job.html#getResults(com.splunk.JobResultsArgs)) (or get preview results) assuming you don't just pass a simple Map with that version of the function signature.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i have updated my question